# .htaccess no me carga los css ni las imagenes

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

Mi siguiente error es con el htaccess no me carga los archivos css ni nada

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog?$ web.php
RewriteRule ^blog/c/([0-9]+) web.php?id=$1`
```

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos una URL de un css que no funciona?

Comment: http://localhost/YOLO/blog/c/css/style.css

Comment: Cambia las rutas usadas de relativas a absolutas

Comment: @JosbertHernandez El problema es que la última de estas 2 reglas coincide con ese recurso CSS, por lo que Apache está reescribiendo a `web.php` cuando se intenta acceder al CSS... ¿Cómo crees que podrías diferenciar los recursos que sí tiene que reescribir de los CSS y demás que no querés que reescriba?

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los problemas al utilizar Urls amigbles **htaccess** es que los enlace y los `link` quedan absolutas:

Yo utilizo esta regla **htaccess** en un proyecto de una tienda online.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?id=$1
```

Si puedes observar en el siguiente enlace http://www.imyshop.tk/vestido-floreado es una url amigable y las imágenes como los estilos, las librerías jquery no están absolutas

`<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

las cargo normalmente sin tener que cambiar las rutas de esta manera `(../js/)`

`<script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Hola, no me sigue igual

Comment: @JosbertHernandez actualice mi respuesta, sobre el tema de tu pregunta espero solucione, caso contrario tendrías que cambiar todas las rutas como ejemplo `(../img/image.png)`. Añadiendo esto: `../` en todas las rutas de las imágenes los estilos css entre otros, seria un trabajo muy largo.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar que el rewrite afecte a los componentes de la página, hay que poner un RewriteCondition antes del rewrite, sino Apache mandará cualquier solicitud hacia web.php, por ejemplo:

```
## solo cambia la URL si la solicitud no es para algo en la carpeta css
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog/c/css.*$
RewriteRule ^blog/c/([0-9]+) web.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Esto supone que tu .htaccess y web.php quedan en /YOLO/, y que YOLO es la carpeta virtual. `[QSA]` permite que el parámetro que extraes con `([0-9]+)` se agregue al querystring. Si YOLO es una carpeta normal, ponle `RewriteBase /YOLO/`

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo estas reglas para el error 404 y 403

```
Options –Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /carpeta/nombre_del_archivo.(php o html)
ErrorDocument 404 /carpeta/nombre_del_archivo.(php o html)
```

y el archivo a donde redirige esos errores es una paginas con sus propios estilos.

Comment: Deberías añadir más detalles a tu respuesta como ¿Cuál es el error del usuario? Y añadir también una explicación breve del código que muestras, pues el usuario se puede quedar con la duda de cómo funciona el código y esta no es la intención de una respuesta.